# Access crosstab query data parameter not filtering query

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access-2013, recordset

I have finally got my crosstab report to dynamically update but for some reason the date parameters are not passing to either the report or the query.

I have a recordset updating the crosstab report and on hover/step through the date parameter in vba is showing the correct date but the report is still showing all data.

The query is also showing data for all dates.  Is it something I have done wrong in the query?  I have tried every option I could find in what seems like every forum and just can't get a solution.

This is the SQL for the query

```
PARAMETERS [Forms]![frm_menu]![txtFromDate] DateTime, 
           [Forms]![frm_menu]![txtToDate] DateTime, 
           [Forms]![frm_menu]![cmbMplTag1] Text ( 255 ), 
           [Forms]![frm_menu]![cmbMplTag2] Text ( 255 ), 
           [Forms]![frm_menu]![cmbMplTag3] Text ( 255 ), 
           [Forms]![frm_menu]![cmbMplTag4] Text ( 255 ), 
           [Forms]![frm_menu]![cmbMplTag5] Text ( 255 );
TRANSFORM First(tbl_logdata.Input_Value) AS FirstOfInput_Value
SELECT tbl_logdata.Log_Date, tbl_logdata.Log_Time
FROM tbl_logdata
WHERE (((tbl_logdata.Log_Date) Between [Forms]![frm_menu]![txtFromDate] 
                                   And [Forms]![frm_menu]![txtToDate]) 
  AND ((tbl_logdata.tag)=[Forms]![frm_menu]![cmbMplTag1])) 
   OR (((tbl_logdata.tag)=[Forms]![frm_menu]![cmbMplTag2])) 
   OR (((tbl_logdata.tag)=[Forms]![frm_menu]![cmbMplTag3])) 
   OR (((tbl_logdata.tag)=[Forms]![frm_menu]![cmbMplTag4])) 
   OR (((tbl_logdata.tag)=[Forms]![frm_menu]![cmbMplTag5]))
GROUP BY tbl_logdata.Log_Date, tbl_logdata.Log_Time
PIVOT tbl_logdata.tag;
```

And this is the VBA for the crosstab report.  The parameters for the cmbMplTag# are working fine:

```
Private Sub Report_Open(Cancel As Integer)
Dim rst As dao.Recordset
Dim db As dao.Database
Dim qdf As dao.QueryDef
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
Set db = CurrentDb
Set qdf = db.QueryDefs("qry_MplTagsSummary")

'on hover shows date from textbox'
qdf.Parameters("Forms!frm_menu!txtFromDate") = [Forms]![frm_menu]![txtFromDate] 
'on hover shows date from textbox'
qdf.Parameters("Forms!frm_menu!txtToDate") = [Forms]![frm_menu]![txtToDate] 
qdf.Parameters("[Forms]![frm_menu]![cmbMplTag1]") = [Forms]![frm_menu]![cmbMplTag1]
qdf.Parameters("[Forms]![frm_menu]![cmbMplTag2]") = [Forms]![frm_menu]![cmbMplTag2]
qdf.Parameters("[Forms]![frm_menu]![cmbMplTag3]") = [Forms]![frm_menu]![cmbMplTag3]
qdf.Parameters("[Forms]![frm_menu]![cmbMplTag4]") = [Forms]![frm_menu]![cmbMplTag4]
qdf.Parameters("[Forms]![frm_menu]![cmbMplTag5]") = [Forms]![frm_menu]![cmbMplTag5]

Set rst = qdf.OpenRecordset()
rst.MoveFirst
j = -1
i = 0
For i = 0 To rst.Fields.Count - 1

    j = j + 1
    Select Case j

        Case 0
            Me.Log_Date.ControlSource = rst.Fields(i).Name
        Case 1
            Me.Log_Time.ControlSource = rst.Fields(i).Name
        Case 2
            Me.field1.ControlSource = rst.Fields(i).Name
        Case 3
            Me.field2.ControlSource = rst.Fields(i).Name
        Case 4
           Me.Field3.ControlSource = rst.Fields(i).Name
        Case 5
            Me.Field4.ControlSource = rst.Fields(i).Name
        Case 6
            Me.Field5.ControlSource = rst.Fields(i).Name

    End Select
skip_it:
Next i

rst.Close
Set rst = Nothing
End Sub
```

Please let me know if I have not provided enough details/information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your SQL `WHERE` clause conditional logic. As is, the logic filters records in either (not both) camps:

1. Falling in the date range **and** query's tag equals only form's tag1
2. Query's tag equals any of form's tag2 - tag5.

Possibly you meant to separate the date range and tags. So wrap parentheses around each condition with an `AND` operator, even use the `IN` clause. See below with indentation to illustrate:

```
...
WHERE (
        (
          (tbl_logdata.Log_Date) Between [Forms]![frm_menu]![txtFromDate] 
                                     And [Forms]![frm_menu]![txtToDate]
        ) 
    AND (
           (tbl_logdata.tag) IN (
                                 [Forms]![frm_menu]![cmbMplTag1],
                                 [Forms]![frm_menu]![cmbMplTag2], 
                                 [Forms]![frm_menu]![cmbMplTag3], 
                                 [Forms]![frm_menu]![cmbMplTag4], 
                                 [Forms]![frm_menu]![cmbMplTag5]
                                )
        )
     )
GROUP BY tbl_logdata.Log_Date, tbl_logdata.Log_Time
```

Comment: Curious, what ended up being the problem? I see you accepted the above answer. Was it the date format?

Comment: sorry, I accepted the wrong one.  It was the parenthesis that fixed the issue

Answer (score 0):

You may have to convert to a true date value. And use the *Value* property:

```
qdf.Parameters("Forms!frm_menu!txtFromDate").Value = DateValue([Forms]![frm_menu]![txtFromDate])
qdf.Parameters("Forms!frm_menu!txtToDate").Value = DateValue([Forms]![frm_menu]![txtToDate])
```